# EF Core 5 - Automatic Many to Many throws "property ... cannot be assigned a temporary value"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

We have a very large context was generated using scaffolding a couple years ago, back in .Net Core 3. We are already running .NET 6 and I wanted to use [the automatic Many to Many relationship creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) that was released with EF Core 5 for a new feature, user alerts. The thing is I configured and created a migration and everything seems to be in place but when trying to create an alert for multiple users and link them with the many-to-many relationship an exception is thrown:

```
The property 'AlertUser (Dictionary<string, object>).AlertsId' cannot be assigned a temporary value.
Temporary values can only be assigned to properties configured to use store-generated values.
```

I can't find anything about it googling around so I know it can be something very specific to our model but everything seems fine:

Alert.cs

```
[Table("Alert")]
public class Alert
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  [Column("AlertID")]
  public long Id { get; set; }

  public string MessageText { get; set; }

  public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

User.cs

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
  [Column("UserID")]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
  public override long Id { get; set; }

  [Column("Username")]
  [Required]
  [StringLength(255)]
  [NonUnicode]
  public override string UserName { get; set; }

  public ICollection<Alert> Alerts { get; set; } = new HashSet<Alert>();
}
```

Basically a user can have many alerts and an alert can point to many users.
To create an alert, I followed the official MSFT docs and several tutorials, I thought I could do something like:

```
var users = await _dbContext.Users
  .Where(u => userIds.Contains(u.Id))
  .ToListAsync();

  var alert = new Alert
  {
    MessageText = message,
    Users = users
  };

  await _dbContext.AddAsync(alert);
  await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But the debugger never reaches SaveChanges and throws the exception in the await AddAsync. I've been trying a couple things that did work like creating the Alert and then updating the users with the alerts for each one, so I think it might be something with the way SQLServer is generating the keys or something like that. I wanted to know if someone else did face this error and what can we be doing wrong.

Also, here's the generated migration:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
  name: "AlertUser",
  columns: table => new
  {
    AlertsId = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false),
    UsersId = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false)
  },
  constraints: table =>
  {
    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AlertUser", x => new { x.AlertsId, x.UsersId });
    table.ForeignKey(
      name: "FK_AlertUser_Alert_AlertsId",
      column: x => x.AlertsId,
      principalTable: "Alert",
      principalColumn: "AlertID",
      onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    table.ForeignKey(
      name: "FK_AlertUser_Users_UsersId",
      column: x => x.UsersId,
      principalTable: "Users",
      principalColumn: "UserID",
      onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
      name: "IX_AlertUser_UsersId",
      table: "AlertUser",
      column: "UsersId");
```

Comment: (1) Does `User` class have a base (noticing some `override`s on properties)? (2) How is `User.Id` configured - as auto generated or not? I see the attribute, but it could be overridden with fluent API configuration. (3)  Does `users` list contain item with `Id <= 0`?

Comment: @IvanStoev User inherits from IdentityUser so I guess it's the underlying base the responsible for generating the ids, but I'm pretty sure is auto generated by the DB. There's nothing configured for that entity in FluentAPI. And I think it's possible to have a user with ID 0 but it's not the case in the tests I've been performing.

Comment: So you are inheriting `IdentityUser<long>` in some strange (and probably incorrect way). Try modifying the class as follows - `[Column("UserID")]public override long Id { get => base.Id; set => base.Id = value; }`. Or remove `User.Id` override at all and configure it fluently - `modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("UserID");`

Comment: @IvanStoev Yeah, I'm gonna remove the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` decorator since I think it's what's causing this to fail in the ultimate way. I'll have to refactor bunch of legacy stored procs but it's worth it. I'll let you know if that fixes the problem.